# How to call a POST method NodeJS API using reat saga call() function?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have used react saga call() function to call nodeJS API implemented with graphQL and AppoloServer. Here is my react saga to call a graphql mutation API:-

```
import {call, put, takeEvery, /* takeLatest */} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import types from './types';
import {
    GET_PLANS_BY_PAGINATION,
    GET_ACTIVE_PLANS_BY_COUNTRY,
    GET_PLAN_DETAIL_BY_ID,
    ADD_PLAN,
    EDIT_PLAN,
    DELETE_PLAN
} from '../../queries/plan'
import client from '../../backend/apolloClient';

// Sagas for Add Plan Starts //
function* addPlanStartHandlerSaga(action)
{
    try
    {
        const {data} = yield call(client.post, {
            mutation        : ADD_PLAN,
            fetchPolicy     : 'network-only',
            variables       : {PlanInput : action.payload}
        })
        if(data?.addPlan?.success === true)
        {
            yield put({type : types.ADD_PLAN_SUCCESS, payload : data?.addPlan?.message})
        }
        else
        {
            yield put({type : types.ADD_PLAN_ERROR, payload : data?.addPlan?.message})
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        yield put({type: types.ADD_PLAN_ERROR, payload: err})
    }
}

export function* addPlanStartWatcherSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(types.ADD_PLAN_START, addPlanStartHandlerSaga)
}
// Sagas for Add Plan Ends //
```

Now I want to make a POST method API call using react saga call() function.

The API URL is this:- //domain.com/create-stripe-account-and-subscribe

In Header, we are sending authorization key like this:-

```
Authorization:Bearer encToken
```

In req body, I am sending data like this:

1. req.body.name;
2. req.body.email;
3. req.body.phoneCode;
4. req.body.phoneNumber;
5. req.body.role;
6. req.body.stripePaymentMethodId;
7. req.body.stripePriceId;

How shall I make the API call?

I did it like this:-

```
import {call, put, takeEvery, /* takeLatest */} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import types from './types';
import client from '../../backend/apolloClient';

// Sagas for Add Plan Starts //
function* createStripeAccountAndSubscribeStartHandlerSaga(action)
{
    try
    {
        const {data} = yield call(client.POST, {
            url             : '//domain.com/create-stripe-account-and-subscribe',
            fetchPolicy     : 'network-only',
            body            :   {
                                  name                    : action.payload.name,
                                  email                   : action.payload.email,
                                  phoneCode               : action.payload.phoneCode,
                                  phoneNumber             : action.payload.phoneNumber,
                                  role                    : action.payload.role,
                                  stripePaymentMethodId   : action.payload.stripePaymentMethodId,
                                  stripePriceId           : action.payload.stripePriceId
                                }
        })
        if(data?.createStripeAccountAndSubscribe?.success === true)
        {
            yield put({type : types.CREATE_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_AND_SUBSCRIBE_SUCCESS, payload : data?.createStripeAccountAndSubscribe?.message})
        }
        else
        {
            yield put({type : types.CREATE_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_AND_SUBSCRIBE_ERROR, payload : data?.createStripeAccountAndSubscribe?.message})
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        yield put({type: types.CREATE_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_AND_SUBSCRIBE_ERROR, payload: err})
    }
}

export function* createStripeAccountAndSubscribeStartWatcherSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(types.CREATE_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_AND_SUBSCRIBE_START, createStripeAccountAndSubscribeStartHandlerSaga)
}
// Sagas for Add Plan Ends //
```

Is it right?